# magento 2 layered navigation price without tax

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I add products to my catalog and in the tax section I select a tax of 21%
When I select the category and display the price filter I notice that it makes me the filter with the price without tax.

[image: layered navigation price]

If you look at the image on the left side the price ranges show the prices without tax.
While in the catalog the prices include the tax.

How can you show the price ranges with tax?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, the current behavior is by design. Because it's the cheapest from the performance point of view solution which fits for most of the merchants.
And there is an ability to customize Layered Navigation (LN) for each particular merchant. 
Because for Price LN in CE edition we use price index "catalog_product_index_price" for faceted search (LN).

For example, in LN building logic we have several places where we use "min_price" for aggregation.

- [Price LN Data Provider](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/99e85cbc45223baa3551e4c534b650c0d2c6358b/app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Aggregation/DataProvider.php#L89-L100) - basic data provider for price LN
- [Dynamic Price LN Data Provider](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/99e85cbc45223baa3551e4c534b650c0d2c6358b/app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Dynamic/DataProvider.php#L89-109), which is used when Price Navigation Step Calculation "Automatic (Equalize Product Counts)" selected as a method for price navigation.
- For the [Filter Processor](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Filter/Preprocessor.php#L157-L168) which is used for applying filtering by Price

So, it depends on merchant specific use case.
If he uses just general price LN (manual or automatic equalize price range) it's okay to customize 1. and 3.
For those who use more sophisticated LN - 2. and 3. is the option.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.  For a generic solution we'd have to add a column to the index for all possible tax & FPT permutations to have performance search/filter functionality.  That'd blow up the index and be a big performance hit.

As an individual merchant you know your business and can limit the # of permutations in a variety of ways.  For most this is a simple customization where you constraint the # of VAT price+FPT permutations and put them in the search index to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer.

I do not quite understand what I have to do, but Would I have to configure it in this section?
[image: FPT TAX]

Comment: Igor's pointing out where you'd create a plugin into the Layered Navigation code to create your custom extension that would alter the out of the box behavior of Magento 2.  By creating this customization M2 would then handle filtering on VAT prices.  This will involve PHP code, XML configuration, your beverage of choice and some time.  Alternatively, we have a number of system integrators listed on our webpage that can provide a quote to create this customization.