# How to Add tax value in Price filter magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.4

I have 100 products and all products have different tax rule and i also do settings from backend to display tax inclusive price display in catalog product list now when i do the price filter its doing filter on normal price and shows the product above the price filter so how can i add tax value in my price filter for better understanding i attach the image.
[image]

Comment: you checked this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/278551/add-taxes-in-the-price-filter-magento-2-3

Comment: @MohitPatel I add the my Tax class in the price filer phtml file but i dont get any reflection in frontend.

Comment: Please answer this question

Comment: You should locate the class that shows the filter.And you add the tax rule class that you have created.

Comment: I add my tax rule class in the filter.phtml file but not result

Comment: Can you please write procedure with code reference

Comment: @MohitPatel your help will be solve many's question because there is no proper answer...if possible please do the code reference.

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176341/magento-2-layered-navigation-price-without-tax

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the below files if customizing them will help in your case!

1. Filter Processor used for applying filtering by Price

```
/Magento2.3.4/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Filter/Preprocessor.php
```

2. Dynamic Pirce Layered Navigation data provider

```
/Magento2.3.4/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Dynamic/DataProvider.php
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Can you please help me to changes in code